# Upgrading from Magen2.3.4 to 2.4.5

Tags: upgrade, composer, magento2.3.4, magento2.4.5, composer-update

I am using Magento 2.3.4 now.
I want try to Magento 2.4.5. But I don't upgrade Magento.
when run command in cpanel terminal, show error like this.

```
$ composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 --no-update --no-plugins
./composer.json has been updated
$ composer update
The "magento/magento-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composerinstallation ("2.2.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "magento/inventory-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.2.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.2.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires php ~7.3.0||~7.4.0 but your php version (7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.5].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 requires php ~7.4.0||~8.1.0 -> your php version (7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Root composer.json requires dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer ^0.5.0 -> satisfiable by dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer[v0.5.0].
    - dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.2.0] but it does not match the constraint.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

I think must upgrade composer and from php 7.2 to 7.4.
Is right? if it's right, how to upgrade composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using composer version 2.2.0, it is compatible with Magento 2.4.5.
2. As you are using Magento **2.3.4**, you can use PHP **7.3** or **8.1** to upgrade to Magento 2.4.5.
   As you are using PHP 7.2, you have to upgrade PHP to 7.3 or 8.1 to upgrade Magento to 2.4.5.
   **After** upgrading to Magento 2.4.5, it requires PHP **8.1**.
3. Magento released version 2.4.5-p1, you should upgrade Magento to that version instead of 2.4.5 to keep your site safe.

You can try one of the following solutions to upgrade your Magento site to 2.4.5-p1 (if solution 1 does not work for you, try solution 2):

**Solution 1:**

1. Switch to PHP version 8.1.
2. Update `require-dev` section in your `composer.json` file same as the Magento codebase: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5-p1/composer.json#L108
3. Run the following commands:

```
rm -rf vendor
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

**Solution 2:**

1. Switch PHP to version 7.3.
2. Run the following commands:

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update
composer update
```

3. Change to PHP version 8.1
4. Run the following commands:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

If you still can't upgrade to Magento 2.4.5 (-p1), edit your question to add the content of your composer.json, I'll help you resolve it.

=== **UPDATE** ===
As you now want to upgrade to Magento 2.4.3, based on your composer.json, I've modified your composer.json to support upgrading to Magento 2.4.3-p3.

Update your composer.json with the following content:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "magento/*": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~2.0",
        "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.4.3",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3-p3",
        "laminas/laminas-serializer": "^2.10",
        "addressfinder/module-magento2": "~2.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.27"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.4",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.77",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.4.3-p3",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "amasty": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.amasty.com/community/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Then run `composer update` to upgrade to Magento 2.4.3-p3 and run the following commands to finish upgrade:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

=== **UPDATE** ===
As you now want to upgrade to Magento 2.4.5-p1, based on your composer.json, I've modified your composer.json to support upgrading to Magento 2.4.5-p1.

Update your composer.json with the following content:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "magento/*": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~2.0",
        "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.4.5",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.5-p1",
        "addressfinder/module-magento2": "~2.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.27"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.5.0",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~3.4.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.7",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.10.0",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.12.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.6.8",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~9.5.20",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.6.0",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.4.5-p1",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "amasty": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.amasty.com/community/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Then run `composer update` to upgrade to Magento 2.4.5-p1

And run the following commands to finish upgrade:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I think use php7.4 for magento2.4.5.
I choose second method, so I did choose php7.4 and then run command like this.
$ composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
$ composer update

Comment: @BohdanV. Glad to help! If this answer helps you resolve your issue, please mark it as **accepted** (the check symbol at the top-left corner of my answer). That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Comment: okay but this answer didn't reslove my isssue.
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.5].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 requires ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer ^0.5.0 -> satisfiable by dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer[v0.5.0].

Comment: - dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.2.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 3
    - Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.5.3 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[2.5.3].
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.5.3 requires php 7.0.2||7.0.4||~7.0.6||~7.1.0||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your php version (7.4.33) does not satisfy that requirement.

I want your help.

Comment: 1. You have upgrade PHP to version 8.1 **after** run composer require-commerce magento/... and composer update. You can’t use PHP 7.4 for Magento 2.4.5. 2. Please enable or install PHP’s sodium extension. 3. Please edit your question to add the content of **composer.json** in your Magento root directory.

Comment: Thanks again! If I cannot use Magento2.4.5, I will use Magento2.4.3. how do you think about? How to upgrade version of live site in cpanel? May I upgrade php version in live site?

Comment: 1. If you can't use Magento 2.4.5 due to your custom code or 3rd-party extensions/themes doesn't compatible with PHP 8.1. You can use Magento 2.4.3-p3 and apply the security hotfix for CVE-2022-35698 (https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/known-issues-patches-attached/adobe-commerce-2.4.3-p2-2.4.5-security-hotfix-for-cve-2022-35698.html). 2. You **MUST** upgrade Magento in a test environment before doing the upgrade to the live site. Once you have done the upgrade in the test environment, deploy the changes to the live site.

Comment: 3. When you **have done** your upgrade, either upgrade to 2.4.3 or 2.4.5, you have to upgrade the PHP version (PHP 7.4 for 2.4.3, PHP 8.1 for 2.4.5).

Comment: Thank you! You are Expert. How to create test environment in local or hosting server?can I create test environment in subdomain?

Comment: @BohdanV. thanks for your kind words. Because you now want to upgrade to Magento 2.4.3. I’ve updated my answer to add the content of composer.json for your project, please check. For question about create test environment, I’ll reply later, I probably give you the answer today.

Comment: should I upgrade to latest composer first?

Comment: Your composer is already on version 2.2.0. You can check it by run `composer -v`

Comment: okay
and I got this errors.
Problem 1
    - web-token/jwt-framework[v2.2.7, ..., v2.2.11] require ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p3 requires web-token/jwt-framework ^v2.2.7 -> satisfiable by web-token/jwt-framework[v2.2.7, ..., v2.2.11].
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-.... -> satisfiable by magento/product-...

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/alt/php74/etc/php.ini
    - /opt/alt/php74/link/conf/alt_php.ini

Comment: That error indicates PHP's sodium extension is missing from your system. Firstly, you should know you are using Apache server or Nginx for web server or something else, then you should search Google to install PHP's sodium extension on Apache (or Nginx depending on your webserver).

Comment: Sorry friend, I'm not supporting on slack or skype. Fighting, go and install that (sodium) PHP extension.

Comment: I want to find way without php sodium extension.

Comment: Unfortunately, Magento requires this PHP extension, if you want Magento works without it, you will need much time to get it done. You can see the list of require PHP extensions here: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/php-settings.html

Comment: okay I installed php sodium and then got errors.
48 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
...
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
126 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Failed to set PHP CodeSniffer installed_paths Config
No security vulnerability advisories found

Comment: And run  bin/magento setup:upgrade 
Autoload error: Module 'AddressFinder_AddressFinder' from '/home/user/test..com/app/code/AddressFinder/AddressFinder' has been already defined in '/home/user/test..com/vendor/addressfinder/module-magento2'.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140998/discussion-on-answer-by-tu-van-upgrading-from-magen2-3-4-to-2-4-5).

Comment: Hey @AmitBera Please bear in mind that only members of The Stack Exchange Network with at least 20 reputation may talk on chat.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @BohdanV. For the first point: it only shows suggestions for your composer package, in most cases, you can ignore them. For the second point: remove the `app/code/AddressFinder/AddressFinder` directory due to its duplicate with `vendor/addressfinder/module-magento2`

Comment: Hi @TuVan I upgraded magento 2.3.4 to 2.4.3-p3 but I cannot see product in frontend and admin/catalog/categories.
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Olegnax\MegaMenu\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor, Argument 4 passed to Magento\Ui\DataProvider\ModifierPoolDataProvider::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/test.com/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php on line 237
I changed  getFieldMap() in DataProvider.php for fix bug.

Comment: Hi @TuVan Can you give  me composer.json for Magento2.4.5-p1

Comment: Hi @BohdanV. I've added composer.json for your site to upgrade to Magento 2.4.5-p1.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rewrite Composer.json
2. Make inventory_stock1 structure in database and copy&paste from old database

   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
   distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
   `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
   `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
   `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
   `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
   `product`.`sku` AS `sku` from
   ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
   (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
3. Run command(if you installed AddressFinder , plz disable it.)

   composer update

   composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"

   composer global config bin-dir –absolute

   bin/magento module:enable AddressFinder_AddressFinder

   php bin/magento module:disable
   {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}

   bin/magento setup:upgrade

   rm -rf var/di var/generation var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade

   php bin/magento setup:di:compile

   php bin/magento cache:clean

   php bin/magento cache:flush

   php bin/magento indexer:reindex

   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

   bin/magento module:enable Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch7

   bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
4. Select PHP 7.4 Sodium Extension
   [image]
5. Install Elasticsearch package in server.

Answer (score 0):

Please check these things :

```
Magento 2.4.5 requires PHP 8.1 Version
Composer 2
```

Please check other dependencies for the 2.4.5

And this is right to upgrading through composer.

Comment: Thank you Rana. Should I upgrade composer first? Could you explain more detail?

Comment: You should upgrade the composer first and then the PHP version. This way seems to be the best

Comment: Thank you
I updated composer and then php version.
should I install php soldium extension?

Comment: Please Install PHP 8.1 FPM with all extensions

Comment: If this help you please mark this an answer.