# Upgdating Magento from 2.3.7 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade, version-upgrade

I am trying to update my magento from 2.3.7 to 2.4.4 using the https://devhooks.in/blog/upgrade-magento-2-to-magento-2-1-via-ssh

But I am getting error

[image]

Comment: I found the solution.
[enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/362256/upgrading-from-magen2-3-4-to-2-4-5)
It can help you.

Comment: I found the solution to fix this error.
[enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/362256/upgrading-from-magen2-3-4-to-2-4-5) It can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before start magento upgrade you need to check magento system requirements as per the version which link is given below and update first if required **Like :-** (php, composer, mysql, elastic search) version etc then start work on it.

You can upgrade magento version using command line for that you need to follow some steps which i have given below.

1. First Enable maintenance mode using a command.
   ==> **php bin/magento maintenance:enable**
2. Take backup of you composer.json file using command.
   ==> **cp composer.json composer.json.bak**
3. Update composer.json file
   ==> **composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update**
4. Composer update
   ==> **composer update**
5. Please run below commands one by one.
   **php bin/magento cache:clean**
   **rm -rf var/cache/***

   **rm -rf var/page_cache/***

   **rm -rf generated/code/***

   **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

   **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

   **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**
6. Disable Maintainance Mode.
   ==> **php bin/magento maintenance:disable**

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy solution to fix this error “your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages” in Magento 2.

Just run the following command.

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

or

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```